# How do I get code to run in Spyder correctly?

Tags: python, spyder

I just installed Anaconda and trying use Spyder editor to run code but it does not show up in the console for any code inputted. An example of the code:

```
#%%
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

I just get the following every time:

```
runcell(1, 'C:/Users/brm64/untitled2.py')
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between defining a function and calling a function? If you don't, please redo a tutorial on functions. If you do, you should know that the contents of a function aren't executed until it is called. How /where do you call the function?

Comment: you need to do make a function call. just write `hello()` below the function and you will see the results.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your `function`, jusk like this :

```
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    hello()
```

it will return as :

```
In [1] : hello()
Hello, world!
```

Also, [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) can give you some idea of your questions.